# Restructuring the directories in linux/unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have several directories structured like this in a parent directory:

```
/app/bpp/cpp/dpp/ASM/Report
/ghh/hhh/hhh/ASM/Report
/hh/ASM/Report
```

As we see above, all the ASM directories have `Report` directories in them along with other sub directories and files. I want a separate directory that has a parent directory to ASM (with ASM only), and ASM with `Report` directory in it. The result should look like this:

```
/dpp/ASM/Report
/hhh/ASM/Report
/hh/ASM/Report
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not absolutely clear what you are asking; do you want to make a copy of the initial directories; do you want rather to move the initial directory to a new location? (Since you seem to want something related to "shell script" you should also tag your question with these words).

The best would probably to start with `find`; the following command:

```
find / -type d -name Report
```

will list all directories called Report; you could pipe the output of this command to `grep` in order to select those ending with /ASM/Report with:

```
find / -type d -name Report | grep "\/ASM\/Report$"
```

this would give to you a good starting point for detecting the directories to be moved/copied.

You can also use the `-exec` option of `find` for directly perform some action on a file or directory found by the command. You should type `man find` in order to see all the power of this tool.

It looks like you will have to search in the whole filesystem; thus `find` may print some warnings (related to permissions), but it shouldn't hurt; you can discard these warnings (if any) by ending the `find` command with `2>/dev/null` for discarding the stderr stream (the error messages).